# Send a message from one Android emulator to another?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I wonder how to send the message from, let's say, the server simulator, which is a Android project and is running on 5554 port to another Android project which is a client on 5556 port? I need this message to display on the screen and I have no idea how to make this connection.

Comment: Are you asking about SMS sending between simulator ?

Comment: You should read more about Sockets programming, emulator is simply an application running on your PC. You can communicate between running applications (processes) using Sockets.

Comment: Not necessarily sms. I'm more interested in push notifications (C2DM for instance...). Thx, Egor, I will ;)

Comment: @lomza I am facing the same problem of sending notifications from one emulator to other . If you know how to do this please reply .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reference the SMSTest sample app uploaded in the Files section. It 
shows how to send SMS between two emulators using SMSManager APIs: 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/files

Comment: above link is broken  :(

Answer (score 12):

using emulator Number (top left of device e.g 5554 , 5556) you can do this.
enter this number as phone number and send message .

Answer (score 1):

Simple sending SMS can be realized by this code

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

If you want to send message from one device to another just put its port into a phoneNumber.

Comment: What about just sending a message? This message can be in TextView in one project and I want to display it as a Toast in another emulator?