# Android sending outgoing SMS from Emulator

Tags: android, sms, telnet

I am working on an #Android application and I know using #Telnet will let me simulate sending incoming SMS to the emulator. Does anyone know if it possible to send outgoing SMS from the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

Code to send SMS

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

using emulator Number (top left of device e.g 5554 , 5556) you can do this. enter this number as phone number and send message .

also see:
[Send a message from one Android emulator to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519685/send-a-message-from-one-android-emulator-to-another)

Comment: Well I knew you could send it from emulator to emulator. I have had issues getting the second emulator to start but maybe if I decrease the ram on each that will work. I was hoping there was a way to send sms from the emulator to an actual physical phone. From what I have read, it doesn't seem likely without access to the service.